# How to set repeating background image for a canvas in Fabric JS?

Tags: fabricjs

I would like to set an image as the background image for the canvas.

It is possible with the `canvas.setBackgroundImage` method.

But it is not repeating throughout the background.

How to make it repeatable?

I have seen demos where pattern is used to set repeating background image for text and shapes.

How to use this pattern for canvas background.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `canvas.backgroundColor` and pattern instead of background image:

```
canvas.backgroundColor = new fabric.Pattern({source: image})
```

Answer (score 14):

According to the tests, bundled with the Fabric.JS, it is possible via `backgroundColor` setter even without passing `fabric.Pattern`

```
var src = 'img/checker.png';

canvas.setBackgroundColor({source: src, repeat: 'repeat'}, function () {
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For fabric 4.6, the [official sample code](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html) works well:

```
const bgUrl = 'https://ossrs.net/wiki/images/figma-bg.png';
canvas.setBackgroundColor(
  {source: bgUrl, repeat: 'repeat'}, 
  canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
);
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/winlinvip/pen/ExwbZoR?editors=0011)